# What means ERROR while installing IRkernel?

Tags: jupyter, opensuse, jupyter-irkernel

I try to install **R kernel for the Jupyter**.

My setup:

- openSUSE Leap 15.4 x86_64 ICEWM
- R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
- Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

I try to install IRkernel with `install.packages('IRkernel')`

But get errors:

```
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmq/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/zmq.h include/zmq_utils.h include/zmq.hpp include/zmq_addon.hpp '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmq/include'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmq/lib64/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/libzmq.pc '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmq/lib64/pkgconfig'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmqsrc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmqsrc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpvwpbvb/R.INSTALL6195291662df/pbdZMQ/src/zmqsrc'
mv ./zmqsrc/Makefile ./zmqsrc/Makefile.done
# ( cp ./zmq/lib/libzmq.so ./libzmq.so )
( cp ./zmq/lib/libzmq* ./ )
cp: cannot stat './zmq/lib/libzmq*': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makevars:56: libzmq] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pbdZMQ’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/pbdZMQ’
ERROR: dependency ‘pbdZMQ’ is not available for package ‘IRkernel’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/IRkernel’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpbxBZo7/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("IRkernel") :
  installation of package ‘pbdZMQ’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("IRkernel") :
  installation of package ‘IRkernel’ had non-zero exit status
```

How to fix the issue?